# Strassen's Algorithm Returning Zero

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

The idea is to create a timer that will return how long it takes to perform a certain function. I sat and coded a matrix class and a `Strass` function that *should* multiply that I feed into it.

The timer function works correctly in that it returns the time that it takes to execute the `Strass` function. However, the `Strass` function doesn't return a matrix that has been multiplied. It is a matrix of all zeroes. It's as if the `Strass` function isn't assigning anything to Matrix C. Ever.

For example, multiplying a 2x2 matrix gives the following result:

```
     0.00 // P1

 0.00     0.00  // the matrix after multiplication 
 0.00     0.00

 7102000 // the time it took to do this
```

The `Strass` function looks like this:

```
public static void Strass(Matrix A, Matrix B, Matrix C) {
    // It has been suggested that P1-P7 should be of size
    // A.size()/2. Changing this does not fix the problem.
    Matrix P1 = new Matrix(A.size());
    Matrix P2 = new Matrix(A.size());
    Matrix P3 = new Matrix(A.size());
    Matrix P4 = new Matrix(A.size());
    Matrix P5 = new Matrix(A.size());
    Matrix P6 = new Matrix(A.size());
    Matrix P7 = new Matrix(A.size());

    // if n = 1 then
    if (A.size() == 1) {
        C = A.times(B);
    } else {
        if (A.size() != B.size()) throw new RuntimeException("Somehow, the sizes of the matrices aren't equal.");
        int sizeOf = A.size();
        // The ungodly recursive calls.
        Strass(A.partition(1, sizeOf/2, 1, sizeOf/2).plus(A.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf)), B.partition(1, sizeOf/2, 1, sizeOf/2).plus(B.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf)), P1);
        Strass(A.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, 1, sizeOf/2).plus(A.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf)), B.partition(1, sizeOf/2, 1, sizeOf/2), P2);
        Strass(A.partition(1, sizeOf/2, 1, sizeOf/2), B.partition(1, sizeOf/2, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf).minus(B.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf)), P3);
        Strass(A.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf), B.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, 1, sizeOf/2).minus(B.partition(1, sizeOf/2, 1, sizeOf/2)), P4);
        Strass(A.partition(1, sizeOf/2, 1, sizeOf/2).plus(A.partition(1, sizeOf/2, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf)), B.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf), P5);
        Strass(A.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, 1, sizeOf/2).minus(A.partition(1, sizeOf/2, 1, sizeOf/2)), B.partition(1, sizeOf/2, 1, sizeOf/2).plus(B.partition(1, sizeOf/2, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf)), P6);
        Strass(A.partition(1, sizeOf/2, sizeOf/2+1, 1).minus(A.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf)), B.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, 1, sizeOf/2).plus(B.partition(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf)), P7);


        C.addPart(1, sizeOf/2, 1, sizeOf/2, (P1.plus(P4)).minus(P5.plus(P7)));
        C.addPart(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, 1, sizeOf/2, (P2.plus(P4)));
        C.addPart(1, sizeOf/2, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, (P3.plus(P5)));
        C.addPart(sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, sizeOf/2+1, sizeOf, (P1.plus(P3)).minus(P2.plus(P3)));

    }

}
```

I've tested the `addPart` function, and it is working correctly as far as I can tell. The same goes for the plus and minus functions. I did my best to go through and verify that I have all of the right sizes and numbers in all of the right locations, and I'm pretty darn sure that I do. So, somewhere in all of this, there is something amiss.

For reference and brevity, I've pasted all of the relevant code [here](http://pastebin.com/zSxA6jye).

Comment: Do you have unit tests around your individual matrix methods to verify they are properly implemented?

Comment: I've tested each of them, and they all seem to work just as I intend them too. I've obviously missed something, seeing as the whole thing doesn't work, but they *seem* to work just fine individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C = A.times(B);` is incorrect.  This assigns a *new* matrix to `C`, it does not modify the matrix object that was passed in.

Comment: What would I do to fix that? (This is a program that I'm doing to learn Java, so don't look upon me too harshly, please.)

Comment: Good catch. I paused on that line but wasn't sure why. Now I know.

Comment: It depends on how you really want the result returned.  I would remove `C` as an argument and instead return it as a result (as in `Matrix Strass(Matrix A, Matrix B) { ... }`).  Then your base case is `return A.times(B)` and your recursive calls change as appropriate.  If you just want to get something working as simply as possible, leave it as is and change the base case to something like `C.copy(A.times(B))`.

Comment: Ah-ha! The numbers still aren't correct, but there are indeed numbers. I'm sure the numerical discrepancy is my own doing though, so thank you very much for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should first test with a 1x1 matrix multiply. Then a 2x2, then a 4x4. These will all be easy to verify. I would also like to point out that your code does not handle matrix dimensions that are not a power of 2, so don't try with a 100x100 matrix. Also strange is that P1 to P7 are the same size as A. Shouldn't they be A.Size()/2 ?

Comment: It's designed to only handle matrices that are a power of two at the moment, so that's okay.

I've tested with many small matrix dimensions, and the result is still zero for some reason. I've edited the question to include the result of multiplying a matrix.